# Clojure CSV Parsing Commas in Quotes

Tags: csv, clojure

I have a CSV file as follow (EDITED: note the space after the first comma)

```
0, "a,a,a,a"
1, "b,b,b,b"
2, "c,c,c,c"
```

and I am hoping to parse each row as a vector of 2 strings, i.e.

```
[0 "a,a,a,a"]
[1 "b,b,b,b"]
[2 "c,c,c,c"]
```

in such way that the commas within quotes are preserved.

However, both data.csv and clojure-csv provide vectors of 5 strings:

```
[0 "a a a a"]
[1 "b b b b"]
[2 "c c c c"]
```

I've tried different values of parser options (:quote-char ") but had still no luck.

Here's my code:

```
(with-open [in-file (io/reader "myData.csv")]
  (doall 
    (map println
     (take 10 (parse-csv in-file)))))
```

Comment: I tried it with https://github.com/clojure/data.csv and I got the result you wanted https://www.refheap.com/98642

Comment: Yes it works with the example above (thanks!)  After some investigation I notice my CSV  has a space after each comma, and that caused parse-csv to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [clojure.data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv):

```
(:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv])
(csv/read-csv (slurp "myData.csv"))
```

It will generate output:

```
(["0" "a,a,a,a"] ["1" "b,b,b,b"] ["2" "c,c,c,c"])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the original question.  The space after the delimitering comma seems to break how the whole parsing works.